# Set EC2 Instance Tag Name for Compute Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-batch

I have a batch job which is trigged with boto3, I run about 10 workers on an ec2 compute enviroment and they used to inherit the jobname from batch but now all my instances have no name tag so it's difficult to figure out which is which.

How can I pass on a name tag to the ec2 instances for my batch job via boto3?

```
    batch = boto3.client('batch', my_arguments)
    batch_detils = batch.submit_job(
        jobName = 'worker_{}'.format(i),
        jobQueue = 'my_queue',
        jobDefinition = 'my_job_definition',
        containerOverrides = {'command': ['sleep 100']},
    )
```

I should specify the ultimate goal is to get each worker with a unique name, not to get the all the same name as the compute environment.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show how you launch the instances? Do you do it with a single `RunInstances()` command, or individually?

Comment: There you go, I updated the question

Comment: @ScottThompson Were you able to adapt the tags defined in the Batch submit job all the way to the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

The [Compute Environment Parameters - AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environment_parameters.html) documentation page talks of a `tags` parameter:

> Key-value pair tags to be applied to instances that are launched in the compute environment. For example, you can specify `"Name": "AWS Batch Instance - C4OnDemand"` as a tag so that each instance in your compute environment has that name. This is helpful for recognizing your AWS Batch instances in the Amazon EC2 console.

Comment: Good for differentiating instances between different compute environments but I used to be able to differentiate actual workers, It would inherit the jobName so if worker_1 had a problem and the CPU flat lines I can easily write some scripts to ssh into it and fix it etc, but now they all have no identifiers so it's a very manual process. What's worse is I can't even get my compute enviroment to scale correctly at all, it will sit with jobs in runnable unless I specify desired CPU > 0.  Batch is actually really unintuitive and seems to have gotten worse since I started using it...

Comment: Well actually, I figured out the CPU thing I think, if you set max CPU > your global instance limit for your AWS account it seems to stick all your jobs in runnable permanently. I still would say this is unintuitive, but the only problem now is the tagging I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

[Boto3 create_tags](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags)

Comment: The problem is I don't have the EC2 instance to add the tag to because the batch job will take a while to spin up.